# Setting div max-width but the div do not auto expand the height

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has been set the max-width.
I input different content in the div and I found that some input (emoji) will let the div expand its height, but if I input all English chatacters the div do not automatically expand its height.

Below is the html code:

```
<div style="float: left;color: #fff;background-color: #00b0ff; max-width:300px;">        
    howdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspace
</div>

<div style="float: left;color: #fff;background-color: #00b0ff; max-width:300px;">
    
</div>
```

And I have attached the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNnlB.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text isn't wrapping because it's one continuous line, if this is how you expect your text to be output then add this CSS style to the containing element:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/6nv9ohfw/1/

Answer (score 1):

If there is no space between the paragraph the text will not break , check with the snippet

```html
<div style="float: left;color: #fff;background-color: #00b0ff; max-width:300px;">        
    howdoyoudoaspa cehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoud oaspacehowdoyoudoaspac ehowdoyoudoaspaceho wdoyoudoaspace
</div>

<div style="float: left;color: #fff;background-color: #00b0ff; max-width:300px;">
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `word-wrap: break-word;` or `word-break: break-all` to text Div in CSS

```html
<div style="float: left;color: #fff;background-color: #00b0ff; max-width:300px;/*word-break: break-all;*/word-wrap: break-word;">        
    howdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspacehowdoyoudoaspace
</div>

<div style="float: left;color: #fff;background-color: #00b0ff; max-width:300px;">
    
</div>
```